# Почему данный код PHP не работает?

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

```
<?php
    class Database
    {
        protected $db_host = "localhost";
        protected $db_user = "root2"; //здесь специально произведена ошибка. Верное выражение - root в данном случае.
        protected $db_pass = "1111";
        protected $db_name = "program";
        protected $mysqli;

        public function connect()
        {
            try
            {
                $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
            }
            catch(Exception $expection)
            {
                echo 'Connection error: ' . $expection->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    $database = new Database;
    $database->connect();
?>
```

try и catch не выводят ошибку!

Comment: А как давно mysqli стал возвращать исключения при своей работе? В пример смотрите http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-examples как ошибки ловятся у него.

Comment: @Visman В примере показан лишь один из способов работы с данной библиотекой. При детальном рассмотрении библиотеки, исключения при соответствующих настройках можно "бросать". По умолчанию - это выключено.

Comment: @Firepro, отлично!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы "бросать" исключения в **Mysqli** необходимо это включить следующей конструкцией перед инициализацией соединения:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Вместо сообщений об ошибках драйвер будет выбрасывать исключение **mysqli_sql_exception**

[Подробнее о mysqli_report](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [описанию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.examples-basic.php) там не выбрасывается исключение. Надо проверять так:

```
if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
```

Ну и там же можно бросить исключение, если это требуется.